# Why onclick() didn't work inside the button tag?

Tags: javascript, oop

I put the `onclick()` inside the `button` tag but it's give me an `SyntaxError`.

I want to delete every rows if I click the `button` in the right corner of every rows.

```
var firstName = document.getElementById("txtFName");
var lastName = document.getElementById("txtLName");
var sex = document.getElementById("selSex");
var age = document.getElementById("txtAge");
var indice = [];
var id = 1;
var remove = "Remove";


var tblPerson = document.getElementById("tblPerson");

function remove(indice) { //remove row one by one
  for(var i = 0; i < indice.length; i++)
      myArray.splice(indice, 1);

}

function print() {
  var objPerson = new Person(id, firstName.value, lastName.value, selSex.value, age.value, remove); //instantiation 
  var display = "";


  display += "<tr>";

    display += "<td>" + objPerson._id + "</td>";
    display += "<td>" + objPerson._firstName + "</td>";
    display += "<td>" + objPerson._lastName + "</td>";
    display += "<td>" + objPerson._sex + "</td>";
    display += "<td>" + objPerson._age + "</td>";
    display += "<td>" + "<button onclick = "remove()">" + objPerson._remove + "</button>" + 
    "</td>"; //onclick gives me a SyntaxError


  display += "</tr>";
  tblPerson.innerHTML += display; //display the output many times
  id++; //increment id
}
```

Comment: The quotation at `"<button onclick = "remove()">"` is invalid. Why use `onclick` in the first place? Use `addEventListener` if you don’t want nested quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a concatenation error in this line

```
display += "<td>" + "<button onclick = "remove()">" + objPerson._remove + "</button>"
```

which should be

```
display += "<td>" + "<button onclick = 'remove()'>" + objPerson._remove + "</button>"
```

or

```
display += "<td>" + "<button onclick = \"remove()\">" + objPerson._remove + "</button>"
```

Except I seriously advise against concatenating html strings because it's not elegant and flexible at all. Use document.createElement() instead.

Comment: It works fine sir. How can I delete every row? If I clicked the button?

Comment: That is a question for another post. Please do check other threads first before posting a new thread.

Comment: I'm just a beginner. My professor recommend this so we can understand how javascript works

Comment: Because this level of dynamic-ness in your html cannot be easily handled by `.innerHTML`. Now that you need to remove a row, `.innerHTML` won't give the appropriate level of flexibility.

Please check out `element.appendChild() element.removeChild() document.createElement() document.querySelector() document.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: I'm not familiar on those methods. But I promise you I study it